# Is there a word/phrase to call someone who hoards knowledge or information?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Knowledge hoarder and information hoarder refers to a person who keeps knowledge/information only for themselves,I am looking for a term that can be used to a person who gathers knowledge/information,like a common hoarder but they hoard knowledge or information

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: _triviamonger_?

Comment: We are called readers....sometimes librarians.

Comment: An asocial philomath.

Comment: Esotericists? Illuminati? Tight-lipped? Could you describe in more detail, how is this person hoarding knowledge? By keeping the mystical secrets secret through murder and conspiracy like the villains in a Dan Brown book? Or just a word for someone who's very good at keeping secrets?

Comment: You've answered your own question. There are many articles online that talk about Knowledge Hoarders as Knowledge Hoarders. What's wrong with that term?

Comment: @jimm101 The existing term refers to someone who doesn't let others know about the information. That's not what he's looking for.

Comment: Using your own terms :  [information gatherer](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Information%20gatherer)

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Answer (score 1):

The question is loaded with the idea of a *hoarder* which might suggest obsessive behaviour, but generally an **archivist** is expected to be diligent about collecting material.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/archivist) has

> **archivist**
> a person who has the job of collecting and storing the materials in an archive

---

About **hoarding**. This isn't really relevant to gathering information. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hoard) says

> **hoard**
> to collect large amounts of something and keep it for yourself, often in a secret place

The idea of hoarding is also to deprive others of a commodity which is (expected to be) in short supply. But information isn't like that; it isn't used up in the same way. Information is copied, and taking such knowledge does not deprive others of that knowledge.

When people say their data was stolen, it doesn't usually mean it ceases to exist: knowledge, data, and information do not diminish by being shared.